# How to overcome 'Suspicious sign in prevented' error from remote server?

Tags: smtp, gmail

I'm using gmail smtp server to send emails. There is no problem when using that on my localhost but when I publish my project to a remote server, my webapplication crashes when it suppose to send email. And I receive Mail delivery error, and Suspicious sign in prevented mail.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "xxx");
```

What should I change or add in order to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new gmail account from the remote server. Now it doesnt complain about Suspicious sign in because IP address is the same with the remote computer. But there should be a more elegant solution for this problem I suppose